# DES encryption from C# to php

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I am trying to port an encryption algorithm from C# to PHP. 
I know that the cipher mode is CBC and the encryption algorithm DES
The initialization vector (IV)  is

```
private static byte[] IV = { 38, 55, 206, 48, 28, 64, 20, 16 };
```

My problem is how the above IV, would be translated in php code?

My php code looks like this

```
$iv = ?;

mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $msg, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pack`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)

```
$iv = pack('C*', 38, 55, 206, 48, 28, 64, 20, 16);
```